# How to disable users from accessing previous page by browser back button after logout in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying not to allow users to go to previous page using browser back button after logout. I wish to show users a messge like "Please login to continue".in Angular 2

Comment: `CanActivate` guards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> create a new file called authorization.guard.ts and add this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {AppContextService} from './context';

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationGuard implements CanActivate {
 constructor(
private appContextService:AppContextService
 ){}
  canActivate(
   next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  return this.appContextService.getAuthAdminLoggednIn();
 }
}
```

> later in your main module import {AuthorizationGuard}
>
> add this in your each router path

```
    {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate:[AuthorizationGuard]
     },
```

> Refer this files for complete authorization 
>   [Refer this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SWs7L5u-cI6i-o6IIeaTmlOIbSH6fW1n)